# How can we access SPPoverBLE profile created in a module using Windows PC application which we are developing in C++

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

We have created a SPPoverBLE profile in PAN1760a BLE module. We need to develop a PC application (for Windows 10) using C++. Are there any libraries available for Windows BLE communication in C++

Comment: http://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm